# Should I turn on ignore bad sectors and create and image immediately?

Tags: data-recovery, chkdsk, hard-drive-recovery, partition-recovery, bad-sectors

Trying to clone my 3TB HDD to a brand new 4TB HDD. But I get a CRC error

**WDC WD30EZRX-00MMMB0 3TB**

**NTFS filesystem**

Using Macrium Reflect 8 I get

```
Clone failed - Error 9 - Read failed - 23 - Data error (cyclic redundancy check).
```

SMART results from Hard Disk Sentinel
[image: https://i.imgur.com/kYrnoBB.png]

important bits:

```
Current Pending Sector Count
Current 200
Worst 200
Raw values 000000000004

Off-Line Uncorrectable Sector Count
Current 200
Worst 200
Raw values 000000000003
```

So I ran to see if that would help

CHKDSK /F /R results:

```
    Chkdsk was executed in read/write mode.  

Checking file system on E:
The type of the file system is NTFS.

Chkdsk cannot run because the volume is in use by another
process.  Chkdsk may run if this volume is dismounted first.
ALL OPENED HANDLES TO THIS VOLUME WOULD THEN BE INVALID.
Would you like to force a dismount on this volume? (Y/N) Volume dismounted.  All opened handles to this volume are now invalid.
Volume label is Data HDD.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
  1380096 file records processed.                                                         File verification completed.
 Phase duration (File record verification): 13.41 seconds.
  304 large file records processed.                                     Phase duration (Orphan file record recovery): 0.44 milliseconds.
  0 bad file records processed.                                       Phase duration (Bad file record checking): 0.15 milliseconds.

Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
  2269 reparse records processed.                                         1786260 index entries processed.                                                        Index verification completed.
 Phase duration (Index verification): 1.69 minutes.
  0 unindexed files scanned.                                          Phase duration (Orphan reconnection): 8.26 seconds.
  0 unindexed files recovered to lost and found.                      Phase duration (Orphan recovery to lost and found): 1.20 milliseconds.
  2269 reparse records processed.                                        Phase duration (Reparse point and Object ID verification): 9.27 milliseconds.

Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
Security descriptor verification completed.
 Phase duration (Security descriptor verification): 494.85 milliseconds.
  203083 data files processed.                                             Phase duration (Data attribute verification): 0.20 milliseconds.
CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
  39868336 USN bytes processed.                                                            Usn Journal verification completed.
 Phase duration (USN journal verification): 1.01 seconds.

Stage 4: Looking for bad clusters in user file data ...
  1380080 files processed.                                                                File data verification completed.
 Phase duration (User file recovery): 4.48 hours.

Stage 5: Looking for bad, free clusters ...
  328534120 free clusters processed.                                                        Free space verification is complete.
 Phase duration (Free space recovery): 4.19 hours.
Adding 2 bad clusters to the Bad Clusters File.
Correcting errors in the Volume Bitmap.

Windows has made corrections to the file system.
No further action is required.

   2861570 MB total disk space.
1614312792 KB in 914776 files.
    224212 KB in 203084 indexes.
        12 KB in bad sectors.
   1575215 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
1314136472 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
 732562175 total allocation units on disk.
 328534118 allocation units available on disk.
Total duration: 8.72 hours (31394898 ms).
```

I've started the long process of using Teracopy with hashing and verification to manually copy all the files onto an external HDD.

**My question is did chkdsk recover any missing files? I couldn't find any "Found.000" folder or .chk files anywhere.**

**What is the next best steps here? Should I try to run a Macrium Reflect Image and ignore bad sectors then restore that image to the brand new 4TB HDD? (running clone with the ignore bad sectors setting on doesnt work) And if I do that will I be losing data on the bad sectors?**

Answer (score 1):

> did chkdsk recover any missing files?

No, all it did was to find two bad clusters and add them to the
bad clusters list. With luck, these clusters are the ones that blocked
Macrium Reflect from making the copy.

On the contrary, if the bad clusters were part of some file or folder,
and if their contents were not salvaged successfully, these files/folders
could now have lost some of their data.

Comment: According ckkdsk log they were in free space, "Adding 2 bad clusters to the Bad Clusters File."

Comment: @JoepvanSteen: The most likely situation is as you say, but whether they were *supposed* to be in the free space to start with is unknown. The poster's chances are very good that they don't matter, but not a certainty.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is did chkdsk recover any missing files? I couldn't find
> any "Found.000" folder or .chk files anywhere.

No, the bad clusters were in free space. see:

```
Stage 4: Looking for bad clusters in user file data ...
  1380080 files processed.                                                                File data verification completed.
 Phase duration (User file recovery): 4.48 hours.

Stage 5: Looking for bad, free clusters ...
  328534120 free clusters processed.                                                        Free space verification is complete.
 Phase duration (Free space recovery): 4.19 hours.
Adding 2 bad clusters to the Bad Clusters File.
Correcting errors in the Volume Bitmap.
```

> What is the next best steps here? Should I try to run a Macrium
> Reflect Image and ignore bad sectors then restore that image to the
> brand new 4TB HDD? (running clone with the ignore bad sectors setting
> on doesnt work) And if I do that will I be losing data on the bad
> sectors?

This is where we enter the realm of opinions.

I'd try if Macrium now is able to clone the drive. I am not expert on this tool. If so, you can forget about the 3 TB drive or examine the more exact state of the drive by running a surface scan (using HD Sentinel for example).

However, even though chkdsk mapped the clusters to the $Badclus file, it does not mean they are gone. Chkdsk simply made sure Windows will no longer try to use them. Also if Macrium is file system based, it should ignore the clusters now.

Ideally (IMO) you let the drive itself handle bad sectors. If you have a licensed copy of HD Sentinel there you should be able to:

- Run a r/w surface scan
- The drive then either determines the sectors are good and it will remove the pending flag, or that they're bad and they will be reallocated
- HD Sentinel is also able to tell if and what files were affected by the bad sectors.

[image]

So ..

- If at all possible let Macrium clone the drive (if needed with ignore bad sector settings). **Ideally you want to clone the drive as a first step before anything else**.
- Then after that deal with the 3 TB drive. You don't want a situation where diagnosing and 'repairing' the drive takes you into a situation where the drive fails and you end up with no clone at all.
- If it turns out you can't clone the drive at all, you find yourself in [ddrescue](https://www.data-medics.com/forum/threads/how-to-clone-a-hard-drive-with-bad-sectors-using-ddrescue.133/) territory. IOW you need a tool that was designed to deal with bad sectors during cloning.

Comment: So I can force Macrium to ignore bad sectors when imaging, but for cloning it throws the Error code 23 still.  Currently using R-studio to image it which I assume it is NOT ignoring bad sectors however it is working (albeit taking extremely long)

Comment: R-Studio can be configured to skip bad sectors.

Comment: is there a similar function like surface scan in R-studio?